# Local Flow Actions and @AuraEnabled Apex wrapper class as output infinite loop

Tags: apex, lightning, visual-workflow, aura

We are building a screen flow for a pre meeting automation. This is in hopes of enabling our users to quickly be able to prepare for meetings. For part of this, we need to enable users to select which documents they want to to be able to run/prepare for the meeting with the client. As a part of this, there are some parts which are a bit too complex for standard out-of-box Flows so we resort to Invocable Apex, Aura Local Actions, and LWC screen inserts to get the job done.

For one of these Aura Local Actions, we want to pass in a list of clients and have a local action populate the wrapper which will ultimately be used in an LWC to display document/report options. The information we pass back from the Local Action should be an @AuraEnabled apex wrapper class which looks like:

```
public class PreMeetingReportWrapper {
public PreMeetingReportWrapper() {}

@AuraEnabled
public Boolean householdReportsAvailable {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public Boolean runHouseholdSummary {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public Boolean runHouseholdProfile {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public List individualReportWrappers {get; set;}


public class PreMeetingIndividualReportWrapper{
@AuraEnabled
public Account selectedAccount {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public Boolean runIndividualSummary {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public Boolean runIndividualProfile {get; set;}
}
}
```

The design file for the Aura Local Component looks like:

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="clients" label='Collection of Selected Clients' required="true"></design:attribute>
    <design:attribute name="wrapper" label='Wrapper class containing all the report information'></design:attribute>
</design:component>
```

The .cmp file of the Aura Local Action looks like:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="clients" type="Account[]" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="wrapper" type="PreMeetingReportWrapper" access="global"/>
</aura:component>
```

The controller Javascript for the Aura Local Action looks like:

```
({
invoke : function(cmp, event, helper) {
let clients = cmp.get('v.clients');

let localWrapper = {householdReportsAvailable : false, runHouseholdSummary : false, runHouseholdProfile : false, individualReportWrappers : []};

let sameHousehold = true;
let householdID;
let firstClient = true;
clients.forEach(client =>{
if(firstClient == true){
firstClient = false;
if(client.CustomerGroupMemberId__r == null || client.CustomerGroupMemberId__r.CustomerGroupId__c == null){
householdID = null;
sameHousehold = false;
}
else{
householdID = client.CustomerGroupMemberId__r.CustomerGroupId__c;
}
}
else{
if(client.CustomerGroupMemberId__r == null || client.CustomerGroupMemberId__r.CustomerGroupId__c != householdID){
sameHousehold = true;
}
}

let individualWrapper = {selectedAccount : client, runIndividualSummary : false, runIndividualProfile : false};
localWrapper.individualReportWrappers.push(individualWrapper);
});

localWrapper.householdReportsAvailable = sameHousehold;
cmp.set('v.wrapper', localWrapper); //Line where the infinite loop is happening
}
})
```

From the flow, this is how I set the variables:

[image]

For reference, `selectedEventClients` is a collection of accounts populated earlier in the flow (confirmed it has values) and `reportWrapper` is a flow variable of type `PreMeetingReportWrapper`.

When I run the flow with this configuration, the flow goes into an infinite loop where the local action never stops running (and keeps running over the same code confirmed by looking at input into the chrome developer console). If I comment out the `cmp.set('v.wrapper', localWrapper);` line, the infinite loop does not occur.

If I happen to change every `PreMeetingReportWrapper` type variable to a String (Text) variable and I change the line in the controller JS file from `cmp.set('v.wrapper', localWrapper);` to `cmp.set('v.wrapper', JSON.stringify(localWrapper));` then the infinite loop does not happen. This means the issue is with the @AuraEnabled apex class or something with my syntax in populating the apex class. So my questions:

1. Is there something that is wrong with my syntax causing the infinite loop at the assignment of a value to the aura attribute.
2. Why does it work when I change to a primitive type such as string?

Comment: I remember there were some known issues related to this (some time ago, don't know if they're fixed as of today). As an alternative you can stringify the object on client-side, and deserialize it in Apex. See an example here --> https://blog.texei.com/lightning-components-auraenabled-method-parameters-whats-working-and-what-s-not-83c351356104